# How to detect if two images are similar?

Tags: c#, image, colors, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I measure the similarity between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images)

how to check if **two images are similar**, not the same, but similar?

Like **color counting** or **bytes** or **something equals**?

In C#.

I need make a tool that recognize duplicate photos on pc.

thanks.

Comment: people dedicate careers to this.  I dont think this can be answered in SO question.  Perhaps there is a library you could use to do this.  Maybe rephrase the question.

Comment: Hehe, Google added this functionality just yesterday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 100% with @MikeOhlsen's comment.

That aside, if you really want to get picky, you can load them in to a `Bitmap` then use [`GetPixel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) and maybe keep track of the % of matches pixels (>= 95% matches are "similar images", e.g.).

Also, similar post: [Compare images in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797895/compare-images-in-c-net)

Comment: I also agree. You have right! sorry